# Convertir a eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo esta consulta que haciéndola correr en workbench me devuelve bien

```
SELECT msg.id, msg.messages,msg.readed, COUNT(cmt.message_id) as total FROM messages as msg inner join comments as cmt where cmt.message_id = msg.id;
```

o esta que también devuelve lo mismo:

```
SELECT msg.id, msg.messages,msg.readed, COUNT(cmt.message_id) as total FROM messages as msg, comments as cmt where cmt.message_id = msg.id;
```

y lo que devuelve es lo siguiente me muestra el **ID**, **MENSAJE** Y **LEIDO/NOLEIDO**, **CANTIDAD DE COMENTARIOS**, pero al momento de convertirla en `eloquent` me tira este error:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: SELECT msg.id, msg.messages,msg.readed, COUNT(cmt.message_id) as total FROM messages as msg, comments as cmt where cmt.message_id = msg.id)"

lo que entiendo este error me indica que no puede agrupar y mostrar la información, en resumen solo puede mostrar el **COUNT**.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que me devuelva en la misma fila EL MENSAJE y la CANTIDAD DE COMENTARIOS que tiene un determinado mensaje?

Comment: Hola @AngelOmarRojasPacheco , Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la pagina para poder ganar tu primera medalla

Comment: ¿cuál es el código de Eloquent de dicha consulta?

Comment: hola la consulta en eloquent es la siguiente:$msg = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT msg.id, msg.messages,msg.readed, COUNT(cmt.message_id) as total FROM messages as msg, comments as cmt where cmt.message_id = msg.id'));